# Php Mysql query give me wrong outpout

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with Mysql query. I wrote this code

```
enter code here
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM description");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              $data[] = $row;
                   foreach ($data as $row){
                       echo $row['name'];
           }
     }



enter code here
```

and my output is:

```
First description
First description
Second description
First description
Second description
Third description
```

I have 3 description in db (first, second, third) and I don't have a clue why he give me something like this.

Does anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Comment: What you are doing here, is printing out all $data after every new row. So 1st time you get `First description`, the 2nd time you have already two: `First description` and `Second description` and the 3rd time you are getting `First description`, `Second description` and `Third description`. To fix this go with [jeroen solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935876/1488915)

Answer (score 5):

You need to move this to after your `while` loop:

```
       foreach ($data as $row) {
           echo $row['name'];
       }
```

First you get all your rows in your `$data` variable, and only then you start echoing them out.

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) returns a dual array: integer AND string keyed. If you'd done:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       var_dump($row);
    }
```

You'd see both keys. Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead, which returns the string-keyed version only.

Answer (score 1):

your foreach loop is inside of your while loop.  move it outside and try.

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM description");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $data[] = $row;
   }
   foreach ($data as $row){
       echo $row['name'];
   }
```

Comment: that said you may consider using mysqli or pdo